# Is there a way to use ffmpeg for RGB to true YUV (not YCbCr) conversion?

Tags: ffmpeg, rgb, yuv

As far as I can [see in the documentation](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavutil/pixfmt.h;h=d41d1ca12fd381058df41cddfb74fa8e21ad13b0;hb=HEAD#l62), all conversions involving YUV actually use YCbCr. There are slight differences though, and I would like to convert to the actual YUV format. Is there any way at all using ffmpeg? As an afterthought, is there any other way that is as fast as ffmpeg?

[image: charts]
<sup>*[Image source](http://www.equasys.de/colorconversion.html)*</sup>

Comment: The colorspace filter uses the upper coefficients, FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. YUV is PAL ITU-R BT.470 standard as used for analog TV, it is not in use anymore. You can use https://github.com/fsphil/hacktv with software defined radio instead.

https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavutil/pixfmt.h;h=d41d1ca12fd381058df41cddfb74fa8e21ad13b0;hb=HEAD#l62

These do not use YCbCr or YUV, those are pixel formats, not color matrices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! when I originally asked the question I knew little about ffmpeg

Answer (score 2):

It turns out it is possible: for example when processing an `AVFrame` using an `AVCodecContext`,

- use `AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P` instead of `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV_420P`  (deprecated),
- or use `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV_420P` and set the [`color_range`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/release/3.2/libavcodec/avcodec.h#L2413) to [`AVCOL_RANGE_JPEG`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/release/3.2/libavutil/pixfmt.h#L460).

All links are relative to release 3.2.

**Edit:**
I believe the actual mathematical conversions are in [`yuv2rgb.c`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/release/3.2/libswscale/yuv2rgb.c#L765).

Comment: Can you link to the source where this can be seen?

Comment: Are you sure the conversion result is "true YUV"? It look like `yuvj` is same as `yuv` with pixel range `[0, 255]` instead of `[16, 235]` for `Y` and `[16, 240]` for `U` and `V`. Assume `jY`, `jU`, `jV` are result of converting RGB to `yuvj` then: `Y = round(jY*((235-16)/255)+16);Cb = round(jU*((240-16)/255)+16);Cr = round(jV*((240-16)/255)+16);`

Comment: I used `ffmpeg` as follows: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=10:size=160x120:rate=1 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -y input.avi  ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuvj444p -color_range jpeg outj.yuv  ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv444p out.yuv`

Comment: These are not YUV or YCbCr, those are pixel formats. These has nothing to do with two matrices above.